# Difficulty playing/understanding video in Django

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, video, sass

I'm trying to play video that I as administrator will upload in a model for playing on my homepage. Maybe later I will give users the option to upload their own videos, but for now I'm just focusing on this basic capability. My problem is that I cannot get the video to render on the page. It may be that my video file is uploading to the wrong directory, or that my html is pointing to the wrong directory. However, when I access the admin and I click on the uploaded file, Django shows a video window with a play button crossed through, so it seems that the Django admin cannot access the video either.

Here's my model:

```
 class Video(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='videos')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Here's my view:

```
 class home(generic.ListView):
model = VideoModel
template_name = 'hide/base.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    v = VideoModel.objects.filter(name='Video 1')
    return v
```

*It may be the problem is with the view and the query. I'm not sure if querying a video file is the same as querying a CharField or whatever.

In my project directory I have a media folder and a static folder. Within the media folder I've a video folder and that is where the video is being uploaded to. From what I've read on Stackedoverflow I should be uploading admin video files to the static folder not the media folder? Still not sure why the video cannot be played within Django admin.

Last but not least here is the html:

```
                {% for video in object_list %}
                    <div class="pane2">
                        <video id="intro" type="video/mp4" controls preload autoplay>
                            <source src="{{STATIC_URL}}videos/Video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
                        </video>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %
```

Let me know if you need any more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't really have anything to do with videos.

For a start, STATIC_URL is for assets that are, well, static - that is, they are provided with the application and don't change. For things that are dynamically uploaded by users, they are indeed saved to the media folder and so you would need MEDIA_URL.

Secondly, you aren't actually using the value from the model instance. Your template needs to iterate through the elements in the object list you send from the view, and for each one needs to access its `video` attribute.

When you do this, you can in fact use the file field's `url` attribute, which avoids the need to use MEDIA_URL at all.

```
{% for video in object_list %}
    <video id="intro" type="video/mp4" controls preload autoplay>
        <source src="{{ video.file.url }}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
{% endfor %}
```

And finally, you need something that is actually serving your media files at MEDIA_URL; Django won't do this for you. In development only, you can configure [the dev server to do this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development); in production you'll need to set up your server to do it directly.

Comment: But I don't understand why it doesn't have anything to do with video when it does in fact have something to do with videos. I have the template language, but did not include it in the original question. I'll change that. I tried your html, but it still does not work. And regardless of whether the video renders, shouldn't the admin still be able to play it when the file is clicked on? I'm thinking that is somehow the root of the problem.

Comment: I meant videos specifically, as opposed to any other kind of file. And as I said in my answer, if you haven't done anything to get the server to actually serve those files, then they won't work anywhere, in the admin or not.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. So I have the following configurations in my settings file:

Comment: MEDIA_URL = '/media/' ---
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Comment: and this at the end of my url patterns: + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: Not sure where I went wrong. I appreciate your help and time.

Comment: Also, other types of files such as user uploaded images and static files provided by the app are being served just fine.

Comment: I found this which is interesting: if I change the html tag from <video> to <img> the beginning of the video will play. About 8 seconds worth. And this is with src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}Video1.mp4".